# Is there a way to build a custom Nifi processor without using maven?

Tags: maven, apache-nifi

I would like to write a few Nifi processors to interact with another project I am working on. My plan at the moment is to write the Nifi processors inside the other project and generate the nar files manually within eclipse. Would that be doable or is Maven absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need Maven per se, although there is a "NAR Mojo" plugin used to put various metadata in the manifest, such as version information and a reference to a parent NAR (if your NAR has one). Other folks have used Gradle, there is a Gradle plugin that does something similar.

If you are building from Eclipse you'll just need to manually construct a JAR file (with .nar extension rather than .jar) that has the processor JAR and any bundled dependencies in the expected format. Do a `jar tvf <already_existing>.nar` to see what the expected structure looks like.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried generating my own NAR, and when I compared it with one produced by Maven it was missing some stuff, most notably everything under META-INF/bundled-dependencies and META-INF/maven/org.apache.nifi. Neither of which are present when Eclipse asks me what I would like to include in the JAR export. How would I go about getting those files such that I'll have the option of including them in the export?

Comment: @spoof Were you able to solve that? I am having a very similar requirement where we don't want to use Maven and pom.XML/pom.properties file.

Comment: Is it including your transitive dependencies in the NAR? If so, perhaps you can change their location inside the NAR, they should be in META-INF/bundled-dependencies rather than at the top level.